# Ubuntu 20.04 freeze mce error

Tags: 20.04, freeze

Ubuntu 20.04 started randomly freezing recently, no keyboard/mouse response (no heavy application running), and I updated BIOS, firmware, but the issue persists. I ran HP system extensive tests (memory test, hardware test, processor test, etc.) and found no issue. From `journalctl` it shows:

```
kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
mce_notify_irq: callbacks suppressed

mcelog shows this:
CPU 0 BANK 5
MCG status:
MCi status:
Error overflow
Corrected error
MCi_MISC register valid
MCA: BUS error: 0 0 Level-3 Generic Generic Other-transaction Request-did-not- timeout
mcelog: Too many trigger children running already
UPI: COR LL Rx detected CRC error - successful LLR without Phy Reinit
<27>Dec 1 18:52:15 mcelog: Location: CPU 0 on socket 0
<27>Dec 1 18:52:15 mcelog: Location: CPU 0 on socket 0
```

Comment: Is your processor overheating?

Comment: I use 'sensors' and the temperatures of cpu are around 35- 50 degree celcius. So might not be overheat?